# Unable to enable the Payflow Pro and Express Checkout in my magento 2 website

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.3, paypal-payflow-pro

I am trying to enable **Paypal Payflow Pro** checkout in my website.
I gave the credential in the admin panel.

Enable this solution  select box is by-default disabled.

I received only username and password from the client.
What i missed in this setup? Please help me?
[image]

Comment: Hello , you are view this link :- https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payflow-pro.html

Comment: Did you enter correct card details or dummy details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enabled dropdown until you will not set value of **Partner** and **Vendor**.

These all field must be required to enable dropdown : **Partner, User, Vendor, Password**

- **PARTNER** :    PayPal or the ID provided to you by the authorized PayPal reseller who registered you for the Gateway.  Case sensitive
- **VENDOR**   :Your merchant login ID created when you registered for the account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Hello @Rohan, what is User & password?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an additional reference from Paypal's article [How do I integrate Payflow Pro with Magento 2.0?](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-payflow-pro-with-magento-2.0-ts2093) for future users. This seems very straight forward and clear.